# word disambiguation algorithm (Lesk algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, wordnet

Hii..
Can anybody help me to find an algorithm in Java code to find synonyms of a search word based on the context and I want to implement the algorithm with WordNet database.

For example, "I am running a Java program". From the context, I want to find the synonyms for the word "running", but the synonyms must be suitable according to a context.

Comment: Here is Perl implementation of the algorithm http://senserelate.sourceforge.net/ you may use it from Java code, but it requires some configuration work.

Answer (score 9):

Let me illustrate a possible approach:

1. Let your sentence be `A B C`
2. Let each word have synsets i.e. `{A:(a1, a2, a3), B:(b1), C:(c1, c2)}`
3. Now form possible synset sets: `(a1, b1, c1), (a1, b1, c2), (a2, b1, c1) ... (a3, b1, c2)`
4. Define function `F(a, b, c)` which returns the distance (score) between (a, b, c).
5. Call F on each synset set.
6. Pick the set with the maximum score.

For starters, the function F can just return the product of the inverse of the number of nodes between the two nodes:

Maximize(Product[i=0 to len(sentence); j=0 to len(sentence)] (1/D(node_i, node_j)))

Later on, you can increase its complexity.

Comment: Umm, no. Distance = the count of nodes between the two words. Wordnet is like a connected graph with each synset as a node. The edges are the relationships like Hypernyms, Hyponyms, etc

Comment: For Lesk algorithm, D = count of words that are in multiple definitions from the synsets

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.d.umn.edu/~tpederse/Pubs/banerjee.pdf) is the perfect document for your problem. The acc of the algorithm is not high but I think it will be enough .

On [this](https://github.com/agreementmaker/jaws) link you can find a Java API for WordNet Searching (JAWS).

Answer (score 1):

Hi i got to have a look at [this](http://www.damn.dk/similarity/javadoc/model/similarity/Lesk.html) page when i was searching for lesk algorithm implementations .
I think it comes as a part of the [JAWS](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html) package . 
i havent used it yet , but i guess this will help